# How to hide browser window in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window, hide

How to hide **(Not Minimize)** a window in chrome extensions
 given its [`windowId`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window), or [`chrome.window`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window) object ?

Here's my code:

```
chrome.windows.create(
    {
        url:"http://www.google.com", 
        type:"panel",
        left:0, 
        top:0, 
        focused: false,
        width: 200, 
        height: 400
    }, function(createdWindow) {
        // How to hide this window object; having its object handler "createdWindow" ?
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Do you mean "Close the window"? Use [`chrome.windows.remove(createdWindow.id);`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-remove)

Comment: No, i just mean set its visibility to false. So that i may later set its visibility to true (i.e show it), & it appears again (without reloading) ... it's like setting a windows form visibility or calling show/hide functions.

Comment: You cannot hide a panel and preserve its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, this cannot be done !

Comment: I'm late, but is there a source that proves this?